# Fail to load converted keras model in node.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm new to TensoFlowjs and I'm struggling to find a solution to this error. I'm trying to train a Blazeface model in Python and convert it to use in node.js.

**My System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 10
- TensorFlow.js installed from npm
- TensorFlow.js version 3.6.0
- Tensorflow.js Converter Version: tensorflowjs 3.7.0;
- Dependency versions: keras 2.4.0; tensorflow 2.3.1
- Node version: 15.14.0
- NPM version: 7.7.6

**The problem**

I trained a BlazeFace model from code provided by https://github.com/FurkanOM/tf-blazeface and adapted it to get 68 landmarks https://github.com/FurkanOM/tf-blazeface/issues/2.
I saved the trained model with TF 2.3.1 `model.save('modelSaved.h5')`

I converted `modelSaved.h5` with `tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras --weight_shard_size_bytes 60000000 modelSaved.h5 converted_models/blazeface`.

The first time I tried to load the model in Js, I got the error:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
await tf.setBackend('webgl')
const modelJson = 'https://***/models/blazeface1/model.json';
const modelLoaded = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelJson);
```

**Error: Unknown layer: HeadWrapper. This may be due to one of the following reasons:

1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().**

After some research I build a HeadWrapper class in JavaScript. The original HeadWrapper is here: https://github.com/FurkanOM/tf-blazeface/blob/master/blazeface.py

**custom_layer.js**

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
class HeadWrapper extends tf.layers.Layer {
  constructor() {
    super({});
    this.supportsMasking = true;
  }
computeOutputShape(inputShape) {
    return [inputShape[0], inputShape[1], inputShape[2], 2 * inputShape[3]]
  }
 call(inputs, kwargs) {
    let input = inputs;
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
      batch_size = input[0].shape[0];
      input = input[0];
    }
    this.invokeCallHook(inputs, kwargs);
    const origShape = input.shape;
    // need something to do here
    outputs= origShape;
    return tf.concat(outputs, 1);
  }
```

Then loading again the model in js:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import {headwrapper} from '../custom-layer/custom_layer';

await tf.setBackend('webgl')
const layer = headwrapper();
const modelJson = 'https://***/models/blazeface1/model.json';
const modelLoaded = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelJson);
```

I got the error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined load**

**Solution**
So, I was able to solve this TypeError based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3566. I had 2 custom layers named "HeadWrapper". I solved this by changing the names of these 2 classes on model.json and building two different HeadWrapper classes in JavaScript.

Now, I can load the model with loadLayersModel :D

h5 saved model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NXzZnBbPcvMBMCxStChhkfhC9TloR47E/view?usp=sharing

Converted model and weights: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OvQTG9wDLDLjZ17TMDNWY4K1RrDtTuSD?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure the path to `modelJson` is correct? Is it on the server or in the browser?

Comment: The json model it's on server. And, yes, I'm sure the path to it is correct. I had problems with permissions and got some 404. And I had the problem with the custom layer. The json is been read. But this 'lenght' problem is unknown :/